# Problem with rgbdslam and QVGA resolution

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, camera-info, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to run rgbdslam with the openni_launch packet setted to qvga via dynamic reconfigure, but when I try I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1367146343.993708402]: PointCloud, depth and visual image differ in size! Ignoring Data
```

If I try to visualize the rgbdcloud from the openni driver in rviz instead I get this error message:

```
Error updating depth cloud: Depth image size and camera info don't match: 320 x 240 vs 640 x 480(binning: 1 x 1, ROI size: 640 x 480)
```

So the problems seems to be the published camera info. In fact, it works just fine with vga 30hz or 25hz modality.
What I have done is only setting the image_mode and depth_mode parameter to QVGA(30hz) via dynamic reconfigure, am i supposed to do something else?

I'm currently using an asus xtion pro live with rosgroovy on ubuntu 12.10.

Any advice is welcome!
Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61689/problem-with-rgbdslam-and-qvga-resolution/) by [Alex2309](https://answers.ros.org/users/4474/alex2309/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2013-04-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Alex,
I've played around with QVGA and also had the problem with the wrong camera info. I think I included some hack to workaround this, but the support for qvga resolution in rgbdslam may be a bit brittle and require fiddling with the settings as I didn't test it much. I am interested in the related bug reports though.

Anyway, the first error you get is because you do not change both images (rgb+depth) to qvga, but just one of them.

Edit:

I checked and I don't get that error. However, I do have problems changing to qvga while everything runs, so I start `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`, then use dynamic reconfigure to switch rgb and depth to QVGA. Then I start rgbdslam (without openni).

Edit2:
I've checked in a workaround for the camera_info problem. Have a look at the new launchfile "qvga-kinect+rgbdslam.launch", it should work "out of the box".

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alex2309](https://answers.ros.org/users/4474/alex2309/) on 2013-04-28**:
Hi, thank you for the reply.
So right now there's no way to use lower resolution for the slam process?

For the first error i setted both image_mode and depth_mode to the same resolution, but i get the same error anyway

Edit: thank you with the new lauchfile works just fine!!

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-05-01**:
You're welcome. Interestingly I noticed that for qvga surf is faster than siftgpu. Might depend on the graphics card and driver though.